# Name of drupal plugin that gives popups for field entries

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

There was a module for drupal that I just can't seem to find now. It basically shows little popup descriptions when you start entering data in a field, as apposed to showing the descriptions below the fields. What was the name of this plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably referring to [beautytips](http://drupal.org/project/beautytips), a Drupal module implementation of the [jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bt) by Jeff Robbins.